# Entity Framework, LINQ: can't use Any with StartsWith?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a simple Entity Framework LINQ query.  The goal is to find all the Carriers that start with A, B, or C:

```
var letters = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" }; // Dynamic, can be many
var results = db.Carriers.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(c => letters.Any(val => c.Name.StartsWith(val)))
    .ToList();
```

I get

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(c => __letters_0
> .Any(val => val == "" || c.Name != null && val != null && c.Name.StartsWith(val)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

Is there no way to do this?

Comment: try : `c.Name.Substring(0, val.Length).Equals(val)`

Comment: Try `.Where(c => letters.Contains(c.Name[0].ToString()))`

Comment: That ought to work.

Comment: Thanks to both of the comments @iSR5 and @Alexander Petrov, neither of the suggestions worked as-is but I was able to combine them into `letters.Contains(c.Carrier.Name.Substring(0, 1)` which appears to work.  The catch is that it will only work with 1 letter, and doesn't have the flexibility of StartsWith

Answer (score 3):

In Entity Framework 6 this query would run fine. EF6 supports SQL translation of `StartsWith` and it supports using local sequences (`letters`) in a query expression.

EF core 3 (the version in the question as the exception message indicates) also supports SQL translation of `StartsWith`. The problem here (which the other answer misses completely) is that the local sequence is used in a way that's not supported. A query like...

```cs
var results = db.Carriers.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(c => letters.Contains(c.Name))
    .ToList();
```

...would be supported because `letters` can simply be translated into an `IN` clause. But of course that's an entirely different query.

Using `letters.Any` requires EF to convert `letters` into "something" that can be joined with in SQL. EF6 does this by building a result set in the SQL query:

```sql
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            N'A' AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            N'B' AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            N'C' AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable3]) AS [UnionAll2]
        WHERE ( CAST(CHARINDEX([UnionAll2].[C1], [Extent1].[Name]) AS int)) = 1
```

Which works, but isn't scalable at all. EF core 3 doesn't support it and there's no easy work-around as suggested in the other answer.

A possible work-around is to build a predicate with `||` (Or) predicates, for example:

```cs
var pred = letters.Aggregate(PredicateBuilder.False<Carrier>(), 
    (p,x) => p = p.Or(c => c.Name.StartsWith(x)));
var results = db.Carriers.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(pred)
    .ToList();
```

Where `PredicateBuilder` is a predicate builder like Linqkit or [this one](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/). But this method isn't scalable either. EF creates a parameter for each entry in `letters`, so you may hit the 2100-parameters threshold in Sql Server.

Answer (score 1):

The Entity Framework doesn't allow usage of custom predicates.
That's the reason why your query is failing with a message:

> ...  could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated ...

So, this most probably means that your EF version either doesn't support `StartsWith` or there is some combination, like `StartsWith` and  `Any` that can't be translated.

A workaround could be:

1. First, you might filter your query with the closest way, by using the [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entitycollection-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8) method.

```cs
var results = students.Where(s => letters.Any(l => s.name.Contains(l)));
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CYB6f1) is a similar example I wrote for .NET fiddle.

---

2. Next in case if you still want to use `StartsWith` but your EF doesn't support that you can convert your query to IN-MEMORY collection :

```
var results = filter_by_contains_query
              .ToList() // convert filtered result to in-memory collection
              .Where(i => letters.Any(l => i.StudentName.StartsWith(l)));
```

where `filter_by_contains_query` is a query from the 1st part.

---

More:

- About EF supported methods check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities).
- Discussions around the `StartsWith`,`EndsWith` and `Contains` [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/474)

Comment: The `s.name.Contains(...)` example will not yield the expected results I think.

Comment: It might well 'work' in the sense of 'execute', but it doesn't carry out the operation desired...

Comment: Sorry, but this answer doesn't make much sense. 1. What is a "custom predicate" anyway? 2. `Contains` is not the same as `StartsWith`. 3. The question is about EF core but you use EF6 in your answer. These versions differ considerably. 4. To `ToList`-trick doesn't work because EF core (3) doesn't translate the `Contains` query either. IMO you should remove the answer and take the rep loss for granted.

Comment: @GertArnold, 1) `custome_predicate` means a query lambda, 2) Contains is not the same, of course as `StartsWith`, that is why 3) in case if the person who used NOT EF core version, but 6th or another version, which doesn't contain `StartsWith` might use the 4) `ToList()` to be applied in order to convert a query to the in-memory collection, which will be already filtered by `Contains` and using the `StartsWith` over.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys, I've updated my answer and now it should be more clear about the workaround that I've suggested.

Comment: I've already updated the answer, with a detailed explanation of how to convert the query result to the in-memory collection and then use the `StartsWith` as a WORKAROUND. Please write your own answer in case if you have a better solution. Sorry at this moment, I could suggest only the above solution and I think that was useful for several people.

Comment: It's useful in case if your EF version doesn't support translation for specific methods and whether useful or not can be treated differently based on different opinions. Again if you have a better solution, I will welcome and appreciate that if you can post it here, or tell me how I can improve the existing answer instead of arguing with me, whether or not you think this answer is useful.

Comment: _"this most probably means that your EF version either doesn't support StartsWith or there is some combination, like StartsWith and Any that can't be translated"_ The issue is that the `Any+StartsWith` is being executed on the input parameter (`letters`). `Any+StartsWith` works when querying a database table, as SQL does support it, but SQL doesn't support query logic on input parameters.

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan See the other answer. Maybe that wil convince you.

Comment: I used method number 2 and it works,thanks